# Association of an image with a Java tree node object 

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode, imageicon

I have a Tree node. I want an image to be displayed beside the node name when the tree is viewed. How do I go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create an ImageIcon from your image

   ImageIcon icon = ....;
   ([there are a number of ways to do this](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html))
2. create an instance of DefaultTreeCellRenderer

   DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();
3. set the leaf icon field of the renderer

   renderer.setLeafIcon(icon);
4. set the tree's renderer

   tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

[if you can't figure it out try the demo](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html)

Comment: to add to the above answer:
If you are looking to set an image on the right side of the text (basically, not an icon) you still need to create your own instance of DefaultTreeCellRenderer to return a component which includes the image

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom leaf renderer .
Override the getTreeCEllRendererComponent () method.

When you render a component .

Use a panel and put the text first and the icon folliwng the text .

And then return the component.

```
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
        boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
        boolean hasFocus) {


    JLabel l = (JLabel)renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
            tree, "", true, expanded, leaf, row, true);
    Component com = renderer.getTreeCellRendererComponent(
            tree, "", true, expanded, leaf, row, true);
    l.setIcon(YOUR_IMAGE);
    l.setText(value.toString());



        panel.removeAll();
        panel.add(this, BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(j);
        return panel;



}
```